# How to fetch Core Data by the order the data was added and display in that order in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am displaying an entity called Skills in a `UITableViewController`. 
I fetch the results like this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)fetchTableData {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Skills" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;

    self.skillsArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
}
```

Also my cell for index path is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    Skills *skill = self.skillsArray[indexPath.row];

    // Skills is a NSManagedObject, I added the Skills.h file.

    [cell.textLabel setText:skill.nameOfSkill];

    return cell;
}
```

And I am adding new `NSManagedObject *newSkill` to Core Data by using `UIAlertView` with a text field in the delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
      NSLog(@"Add button clicked");
      NSString *newSkillText = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
      NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
      Skills *newSkill = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Skills" inManagedObjectContext:context];
      newSkill.nameOfSkill = newSkillText;
      [self.skillsArray addObject:newSkill];
    } else {
       // Do something else
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Every time I reload the data the cells are displaying the data in the order the data was added but if dismiss the view controller and return the cells display the data in a different order than added? The weird part is that I am using this same exact code to add core data and retrieve it in another `UITableViewController` and it never displays out of order. The data added in this `UITableViewController` is as follows: I am pushing to another `UIViewController` and add the information there and then dismiss back to the tableview. In this code I am adding the information while in the view controller is being presented, maybe that could have something to do with it?

Also I know I could add an NSSortDiscriptor such as:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"nameOfSkill" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
```

but it does it by the name and I want by the way it was added without having to add another attribute for index cause I never did that to my other data and it always displays in the order it was added.

Comment: There is no default sort for Core Data.  [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888028/are-core-data-fetches-nsfetchrequest-sorted-in-any-specific-fashion-by-default?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get the data as it is. You will have to insert a field of "Time" and you can sort according to it.

OR

Add a unique field of 'data_id' . Always check the count before inserting the data. And give the data_id accordingly adding 1 to the count. Then after fetching the data from core data sort it as per data_id.

You can do as per you like.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add an Attribute to sort on...either an updating, incrementing counter, or the timestamp of the insertion. If you subclass NSManagedObject, ou can write this value in `-awakeFromInsert`. Then your tableview's fetch request will sort on that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For the desired result you need to sort it according to timestamp or primary key which is auto-generated by core data database.

Core Data makes its own primary key - you don't have to add one. You can retrieve it with

NSManagedObjectID *moID = [managedObject objectID];

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the sorting of the objectID will be in the order the objects was created. Just make a property with a timestamp.